# Error Placement Issue for the required fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

[image] I have an issue with error placement for the required field and it overlaps exactly on the labels of the field and I'm using bootstrap modal with class **form-label-group** and it works fine if I remove the class. I want to show the error messages within the span of each input fields. It's really hard for the users to check the field names when I validate the form before submit.

```js
$('#Test').validate({
  errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
  errorClass: 'help-block', // default input error message class
  focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
  ignore: "",
  rules: {
    FName: {
      required: true
    },
    LName: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  invalidHandler: function(event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit
  },
  highlight: function(element) { // hightlight error inputs
    $(element)
      .closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group
  },
  success: function(label) {
    label.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    label.remove();
  },
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.closest('.input-icon').length === 1) {
      error.insertAfter(element.parent("span"));
    } else {
      error.insertAfter(element.parent("span"));
    }
  },
});

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
  <form id="Test" action="#" class="addForm floating-labels m-t-40">


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" id="FName" name="FName" value="" class="form-control" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" maxlength="50">
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <label for="FName">First Name*</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" id="LName" name="LName" value="" class="form-control" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" maxlength="50">
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <label for="LName">Last Name*</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, change `element.parent("span")` to `element.next("span")`

Comment: Hello, I have the same issue and added the screenshot to the original post

Comment: are you seeing that behaviour [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6tpxo7gL/) as well ?

Comment: For some reason it's not showing here: https://jsfiddle.net/t25ohkd9/ , I added a modal and was not able to replicate my issue.

Comment: maybe something else might be causing problem then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Swati and it worked. The issue was in one of my class, which was causing the issue.
element.parent("span") to element.next("span")